# Date substract in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date

How do I subtract `dates` in JavaScript?
I have a string of a `date` and i would like to subtract from it another date.
I would like to do that in a function:

```
function substractDate(date1, date2){
}
```

How can i that in proper JavaScript?

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
var date1 = new Date(),
    date2 = new Date();

function subtractDate(date1, date2) {
    subtracted = new Date(+date1 - +date2);
    return subtracted;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eSd98/).

Comment: If `date1` and `date2` are `Date` objects, you can omit the unary `+` operator.

Comment: @MaxArt ooh, I never knew that!

Comment: It works for every object that has a `valueOf` method ;) For `Date` objects, it's the same of `getTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
var dtOne = new Date( "2014/01/01" );
var dtTwo = new Date( "2014/02/02" );
var dtDelta = Math.abs( dtOne - dtTwo );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// will get second
var substract = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 1000;
```